# Eclipse 4.11.0 with CDT crashes java when opening source file

Tags: eclipse

I have been using Eclipse Helios with CDT (not sure which version of CDT) for a while and haven't had a problem but wanted to get the eGit plugin.  Our system administrators found that Eclipse 4.11.0 (Juno?) had eGit packaged with it and have installed it on our workstation running RHEL 6.10.
I imported my projects from Helios to Juno in a separate workspace but when I try to open a file java seg faults.
After it crashes I get a popup message from the system stating:

> Use a privileged user account to report the problem in the
> java-1.8.0-opendjk-headless-1.8.0.212.b04-0.el6_10 package

When I do java -version, I get:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment: (build 1.8.0.212-b04)
>
> OpenJDK 64-bit ServerVM (build 24.212-b04, mixed mode)

The .metadata/.log/.log file has the following:

> eclipse.buildId = M20120914-1800
>
> java.version = 1.8.0_212
>
> java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
>
> BootLoader Constants: OS=linux ARCH=x86_64 WS=gtk NL=en_US
>
> Framework Arguments: -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
>
> Command-line Arguments: -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

I've been trying to get my system administrators to figure this out for about a month and since it doesn't seem to be a high priority for them I figured I'd go looking on my own.
Does anyone have any idea on what is wrong or how I can fix it?

Comment: Eclipse Juno (4.1 not 4.11) is ancient, had problems, and won't work with newer builds of Java. Use the current release of Eclipse (2019-09, 4.13)

Comment: @greg-449 beat me to it; I was just about to say the same thing: upgrade to the latest release of Eclipse. You might also consider upgrading to the latest release of Java 8 (8u231).

Comment: If it were only that easy.  Unfortunately the network that I'm on doesn't allow us to just download the new version and install it.  There are complications due to the fact that the Eclipse Foundation is in Canada and could add months to getting it approved.

Comment: Turns out the System Administrator loaded Eclipse 4.2.1.  I was able to get a copy of 4.11.0 loaded but am different issues with that.